# Hibernate create Index after initial load

Tags: performance, hibernate, indexing, lucene, hibernate-search

I am creating a new schema using Hibernate. I know how to create index using @Index annotation.

But this would create index before my initial load. This slows down my load phase.

I want to be able to create indexes after my initial load is complete. Any parameter I can set or create index in my client using Hibernate Java functions?

**Update:**
Also I read about Lucene index with Hibernate. Is it a practical for update heavy actions? Since I plan to use Indexes anyway.

Comment: Is hibernate creating your schema with hbm2ddl.auto?

Comment: Yes! any other alternative?